# VsCode installing C# dependencies

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a weird "problem" since this morning. I'm using vscode to program in Unity, everything works fine but now, whenever I open VsCode or open a folder or close a window, the terminal opens and shows this:

```
Installing C# dependencies...
Platform: win32, x86_64

Finished
```

And it seems that nothing is installed. Everything works fine, but really annoying to work like this. I have uninstalled and reinstalled everything but still the same.

Thanks in advance, regards.

**EDIT**

This issue was reported on Omnisharp github and this user's solution works for me
[Fix terminal reports installing C# dependencies with no installing nothing](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/5015#issuecomment-1023835920)

Answer (score 2):

(For anyone having this same error, please check **end0's answer on the question or in the comments** for a more in-depth solution instead of a temporary one)

I had the same problem, I solved it by disabling the extension "Debugger for Unity".

Try making a workspace for your unity project and on the same extension, click the dropdown button next to "enable" and enable it only for that workspace.

[Enabling "Debugger for Unity" only in the workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zndTe.png)

Comment: Yes, I did it temporarily. This issue was reported on Omnisharp github and today a user told how to fix it. This works for me.https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/5015#issuecomment-1023835920